# Mandt Specified Multiple Times But Not in Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I get this error

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 67
>   The column 'MANDT' was specified multiple times for 'cte'."

when attempting to run the code below however I am not including the column `MANDT` in my query. Both tables that I am calling do have a column `MANDT`, but they both have the column `STAT` as well and I did not have a problem with another table attempting the same join, the only thing is that table did not have `MANDT`, only `STAT` was the same.

I attempted to include both columns `MANDT` with an alias: `JCDS_SOGR.MANDT as Client` and `TJ30T.MANDT as Client2` separately and together, this did not pan out. Got the same error message.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STAT ORDER BY UDATE) AS Rn,
        *,
        LAG(UDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY STAT ORDER BY UDATE) AS PrevUDate,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY STAT) AS [Count]
    FROM
        JCDS_SOGR
    JOIN
        TJ30T on JCDS_SOGR.STAT = TJ30T.ESTAT
    WHERE
        OBJNR = 'IE000000000010003137'
)
SELECT
    MAX(rn) AS [Count],
    OBJNR, STAT, TXT30,
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN rn % 2 = 0 
              THEN DATEDIFF(d, PrevUDate, UDATE) 
           WHEN rn = [Count] 
              THEN  DATEDIFF(d, UDATE, GETDATE())   
           ELSE 0 
        END) AS DIF
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    OBJNR, STAT, TXT30
```

This is the other query I referred to that works fine with this same code.

```
;with cte
AS
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by STAT Order by UDATE ) as Rn  
      , *
      , LAG(UDATE) OVER(partition by STAT Order by UDATE ) As PrevUDate
      , COUNT(*) OVER(partition by STAT) As [Count]
    from JCDS_SOGR
    join TJ02T on JCDS_SOGR.STAT = TJ02T.ISTAT
    where OBJNR = 'IE000000000010003137'
    and TJ02T.SPRAS = 'E'
)
select Max(rn) As [Count]
  , OBJNR,STAT,TXT30 
  , SUM(CASE WHEN rn%2=0 THEN DATEDIFF(d,PrevUDate,UDATE) 
    WHEN rn=[Count] THEN  DATEDIFF(d,UDATE,getDate())   
    ELSE 0 END) as DIF
from cte
group BY OBJNR, STAT,TXT30
```

The expected result is this

```
[COUNT   OBJNR                  STAT    TXT30           DIF
1   IE000000000010003137    I0099   Available   2810][1]
```

Comment: In your CTE, you are selecting *. So if you have two columns named MANDT, this could cause a conflict.  If you remove *, do they work better?

Comment: So I now received this error. "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 88
Invalid column name 'OBJNR'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 88
Invalid column name 'STAT'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 88
Invalid column name 'TXT30', etc"  I will try and add back certain fields and see.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much.

Comment: Would you mind if I post the answer, so I can get a few points?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course not thank you so much for the help. I responded with the check please let me know if it doesn’t work as I am not at the stage to start effectively voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CTE, you are selecting *. So if you have two columns named MANDT, this could cause a conflict. Remove *.  That should fix the problem that you described.